# WSO2 analytics is breaking when email username is enabled in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

As mentioned in document here https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#StandardSetup

When email username is enabled in WSO2 APIM then  must be admin@wso2.com@carbon.super. Also same username is kept in user-mgmt.xml under  in WSO2 APIM. Well this set up is breaking and I am not able to see analytics from WSO2 APIM publisher. Does anyone knows what's wrong with analytics when email username is enabled? Below is log from both WSO2 APIM and Analytics. Please note in below log I have truncated some lines of logs since they were so may lines and was creating problem while posting but main error line is shown properly.

**WSO2 APIM log**:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2019-01-02 12:55:31,408] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://das.wso2-test:7712. {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://das.wso2-test:7712.
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:131)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to the data receiver.
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:125)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
```

**Analytics log**:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-02 11:55:33,464] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin@wso2.com@carbon.super connected {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-02 11:55:33,464] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authentication.AuthenticationServiceImpl} - Invalid User : admin@wso2.com {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authentication.AuthenticationServiceImpl}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-02 11:55:33,464] ERROR {org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer} - Thrift error occurred during processing of message. {org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer}
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'message' was not present! Struct: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:null)

TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-02 11:55:33,465] WARN {org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport} - Error closing output stream. {org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport}
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

I tried all possible approach mentioned in documents but still analytics is not working when email username. Is this already existing issue in WSO2 APIM 2.1.0? I'm asking because I found exact same issue open in github https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/issues/583

**api-manager.xml**:

```
<ThrottlingConfigurations>
    <EnableAdvanceThrottling>true</EnableAdvanceThrottling>
    <DataPublisher>
        <Username>admin@wso2.com@carbon.super</Username>

<Analytics>
    <DASUsername>admin@wso2.com@carbon.super</DASUsername>
    <DASPassword>${admin.password}</DASPassword>
```

**usr-.xml**:

```
<UserName>admin@wso2.com@carbon.super</UserName>
<Password>admin</Password>
```

**carbml**:

```
<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>
```

Also changes **jndi.properties**:

```
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin!wso2.com!carbon.super:admin@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://${xxx.trafficManager.host}:${xxx.trafficManager.jms.port}'

connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin!wso2.com!carbon.super:admin@clientID/test?brokerlist='tcp://${xxx.trafficManager.host}:${xxx.trafficManager.jms.port}'
```

Analytics should work even after enabling email username.

Comment: Did you enable email username in analytics server also. username and password in <Analytics> section of api-manager.xml should contain credentials of analytics server. Not APIM

Comment: I didn't modify api-manager.xml but yes I enabled <EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>  in carbon.xml. Also did changes in user-mgmt.xml <UserName>admin@wso2.com@carbon.super</UserName> and most importantly I changed datasource from jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB to jdbc/WSO2UM_DB in usr-mgmt.xml. Updated master-datasources.xml with datasources WSO2AM_DB, WSO2UM_DB, WSO2REG_DB and WSO2_MB_STORE_DB. After doing all these analytics started working.

Comment: Above changes are done in analytics server.

Comment: Great to hear that. I'll add the answer accordingly

Comment: @Tishan I meant its mandatory to have those email id configuration in publisher, store, IS and gateways but apart from those we should have changes in analytics as well. In WSO2 documentation its not properry mentioned how we should put email id related configuration in analytics which was reason I was stuck and my analytics was breaking. But finally when I went to analytics java code and found that it's using same library as APIM. That's why I did email related changes and datasource in analytics.